# What's the difference between Ruby Core API and Standard Library API?

Tags: ruby

[Ruby Doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/) has two sections: Core and Standard. Core comes by default and standard has additional libraries/methods etc. Does it mean I have to `require` these standard libraries in order to use them? I thought so and picked `DateTime.now` from standard library without requiring anything, and it worked.

Comment: Your description is wrong. `DateTime.now` returns an error without `require "date"` or `require "time"`.

Comment: @sawa: you are right, I didn't fireup a new irb and used the one which I was playing with. So I might have loaded some other library.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yep, you got it right. Core functionality is everything you don't have to `require` to use.

`DateTime` seems to be not in the core (are you running your line inside of rails console, maybe?)

```
DateTime.now # => 
# ~> -:1:in `<main>': uninitialized constant DateTime (NameError)
```

But `Time` is

```
Time # => Time
Time.now # => 2013-08-29 12:32:54 +0400
```

Only a few methods of `Time` are in core, though. To get more functionality (like `Time.parse`) you have to

```
require 'time'
```

Comment: OP is asking something different - *I thought so and picked DateTime.now from standard library without requiring anything, and it worked.* But for me it is not the case... I don't know how OP did that. I am in Ruby 1.9.3...

Comment: My guess is that he tried it in rails console (or some other "loaded" IRB session). `DateTime` is not in the core.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev and @ Babai : I have wasted your time and my time, trying the same in new irb threw an error.