# Is an `include` necessary when accessing Ruby core objects?

Tags: ruby

In the documentation for Ruby's `Comparable` module, the code sample (at the top of [this page](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Comparable.html)) has `include Comparable`.

[My understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18505925/3160817) was that any object that is *within* the Ruby core does *not* need to be "included" or "required." And since the `Comparable` module's documentation page has `core-2.2.3` in its URL, it seems that this module is in the Ruby core.

So essentially, why is the `include` necessary here?

Comment: Because you're including the module in the class definition. It's not like an `import` in other languages--`include` modifies the class being defined.

Comment: It seems like you are confusing inclusion of a module and requiring a library.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the include is necessary and here's why. The `Comparable` module is a mixin, meaning it is a class that contains methods that allows itself to be used by other classes without having to be the super/parent class for the other classes.

So how a particular class gains access to the mixin features is by including it rather than inheriting directly from the `Comparable` class. In `OOP` this often done to avoid multiple inheritance of a single class.

Comment: Gotcha. That makes sense. As a follow-up question though... Why don't I have to `include String` (for example) when creating a class that uses Ruby Core's built-in `String` class. I'm just trying to wrap my brain around when to use `include` and when doing so isn't necessary.

Comment: @filmnut The String class is an actual object which inherits from the `Object` class, which most of the core classes inherits from in ruby. The example above class (`Comparable`) is a module so it has no parent class. So if you include the `Comparable` module into your class you would have access to all of its methods inside of your custom class.

Comment: @filmnut Using `String` is fine, strings are actual objects by themselves. And you're not trying to add `String`'s behavior to your own models. And even if you were you'd subclass it, since it's an actual string. As mnemonic, try to remember that `include SomeModule`, will essentially include the module's methods in the current class.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Those distinctions help a lot.