# Additions Time Class Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm in trouble. I would be very grateful if you can help me.

I have to add and subtract times with ruby. I have a hash that has the times of each stage of the competitors, but I have to add the times to get the final time. I enclose codes that I have made to try.

```
 {"Name"=>"Jhon doe", "Stage 1"=>"07:18.713", "Stage 2"=>"07:31.602", "Stage 3"=>"07:37.464", "Stage 4"=>"09:58.272", "Stage 5"=>"06:47.872", "Stage 6"=>"07:35.579"}
```

The problem is that when doing the addition, it recognizes me what is inside the hash as a string, is there any way to convert it to time and to be able to do the addition and subtraction?

Comment: First I'd search the web for "ruby how to convert string duration to time" or something like that--you can almost certainly solve this problem on your own.

Comment: Friend, I really tried before I wrote this post, but I still can't solve it.

Comment: What did you try? Why didn't it work? Even doing it "by hand" would be simply breaking up a duration string, converting to numbers, and doing some simple math.

Comment: Try using parse.  Time.parse(row["time"]), however it returns an error: undefined method `parse 'for Time: Class.

Comment: @MiguelAbdonHollstein https://stackoverflow.com/a/18505925/125816

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Time::parse`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.5/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-parse) or [`Time::strptime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.5/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-strptime) in the Time standard library to parse a string.

```
require 'time'

string = "07:18.713"
time   = Time.strptime(string, '%R')
#=> 2019-10-24 07:18:00 +0200
```

When you doing this for multiple times you might want to pass it the "now" argument. Imagine the code running just before midnight, then during iteration the day jumps forward changing the "now" argument for the remainder of the loop:

```
hash =  {"Name"=>"Jhon doe", "Stage 1"=>"07:18.713", "Stage 2"=>"07:31.602", "Stage 3"=>"07:37.464", "Stage 4"=>"09:58.272", "Stage 5"=>"06:47.872", "Stage 6"=>"07:35.579"}
now = Time.now # Save the current time in a variable so all parsing uses
               # the same now time.

stage_times = hash.slice(*'Stage 1'..'Stage 6')
stage_times.transform_values! { |time| Time.strptime(time, '%R', now) }

result = hash.merge(stage_times)
#=> {"Name"=>"Jhon doe", "Stage 1"=>2019-10-24 07:18:00 +0200, "Stage 2"=>2019-10-24 07:31:00 +0200, "Stage 3"=>2019-10-24 07:37:00 +0200, "Stage 4"=>2019-10-24 09:58:00 +0200, "Stage 5"=>2019-10-24 06:47:00 +0200, "Stage 6"=>2019-10-24 07:35:00 +0200}
```

Comment: Did that `Time.parse` really work for you? Did not for me: `ArgumentError (yday 713 out of range)`.

Comment: `Time.parse` does work for me, but you could also use `Time.strptime(string, '%R')` to extract only the hours and minutes. Or `'%R.%L'` to extract hours, minutes and milliseconds (assuming `.nnn` are the milliseconds). Check the link in the answer for the formatting options.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of format specifiers here, thanks. :) Which ruby have you used? I tried in a plain 2.6.3 irb session.

Comment: Currently running RVM (MRI) Ruby 2.4.1, executed the snippet by pasting it in irb, haven't tried to run it as script. But it might have something to do with the system locale.

Comment: Yeah, most likely. Working with time is hard.

Comment: `parse` is locale dependent and does the wrong thing with values in `mm/dd/yyyy` format because it expects `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Comment: @theTinMan I've updated the answer to use `strptime` to avoid any confusion about the behaviour of `parse`.

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much for your help, I found in different posts and managed to solve my problem. I leave the answer in case you can help someone. Finally I had to convert everything into Millesimas of seconds, make the addition of the times and then convert back to time format. It was all manual, add some "IF" because it is the way I need it to look. Maybe it's not the best way but I managed to solve my problem. Thank you all.

```
 t = 426475
 ss, ms = t.divmod(1000)          
 mm, ss = ss.divmod(60)           
 hh, mm = mm.divmod(60)          
 dd, hh = hh.divmod(24) 

 if hh<10
     hh = "0"+hh.to_s
 else
     hh = hh.to_s
 end

 if mm<10
     mm = "0"+mm.to_s
 else
     mm = mm.to_s
 end

 if ss<10
     ss = "0"+ss.to_s
 else
     ss = ss.to_s
 end

 if ms <10
     ms = "00"+ms.to_s
 else
     if  ms<100
      ms = "0"+ms.to_s
     else
      ms = ms.to_s
 end
end


if hh == "00"
     puts mm+":"+ss+"."+ms

else
     puts hh+":"+mm+":"+ss+"."+ms
end
#=> 07:06.475
```